# How to add Header Name in UITableViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: swift, uitableview, diffabledatasource, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I try to add header title for each section in `UITableView`, but in this case it's `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` and I don't have any idea where I should do that. A part of my code:

```
private func prepareTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Sections, User>(tableView: tableView, cellProvider: { (tableView, indexPath, user) -> UITableViewCell? in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        return cell
    })
}

private func addElement(_ user: User) {
    var snap = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Sections, User>()
    snap.appendSections([.main, .second])
    if isFirst {
        users.append(user)
    } else {
        secondUsers.append(user)
    }
    snap.appendItems(users, toSection: .main)
    snap.appendItems(secondUsers, toSection: .second)
    isFirst.toggle()
    dataSource.apply(snap, animatingDifferences: true, completion: nil)
    dataSource.defaultRowAnimation = .fade
}
```

`UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` has a parameter `supplementaryViewProvider` where user can configure headers. Does exist something like this in `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to do that by subclassing the `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` class like this:

```swift
class MyDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Sections, User> {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Hello, World!"
    }
}
```

and then in your code instead of this:

```swift
dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Sections, User>
```

use your own Data Source class:

```swift
dataSource = MyDataSource<Sections, User>
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, see the `supplementaryViewProvider` property of `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`

Apple doesn't really have much [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3255142-supplementaryviewprovider) of it, but you can initialize it with a closure similar to how you initialize the diffable data source itself. It returns a `UICollectionReusableView` which can either be a generic view, or one of your header or footer view subclasses.

Comment: the question is about UITableViewDiffableDataSource not Collection view